# Logback initialization

Tags: java, logback

I start java application with this configuration to force use my configuration of logback and never write on standard output:

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=$FOLDER/logback-server.xml
```

But on start the software write logback initialization on standart output.
Why ?

My logback file logback-server.xml look like:

```
<configuration debug="true">
<!-- CONSOLE appender -->
<appender name="FILE-INFO" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>myFolder/logs/-info.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>info.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy_HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %marker [%c{40}] %m%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="FILE-ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>myFolder/logs/error.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy_HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %marker [%c{40}] %m%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- use appenders -->
<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
</root>

</configuration>
```

and the first output is:

```
11:42:14,502 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [myFolder/logback-server.xml] at [file:myFolder/logback-server.xml]
11:42:14,669 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
11:42:14,671 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
11:42:14,678 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE-INFO]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You requested that to happen with this line in your configuration file:

```
<configuration debug="true">
```

Debug info from logback initialization always goes to the standard output; otherwise you'd have a chicken-and-egg problem trying to set up your configuration.

Comment: i change debug config to false but I always standard output in init phase

Comment: There is also a system property you can set to get that output. Perhaps you have that as well.